# Can a function belong to just the block scope it is declared in?

Tags: javascript

If I declare a function inside an {...} block it is available outside the scope of the block.
Can functions be attached just to block scope without using any special declarations like immediately invoked functions.

Comment: `let` and `const` plus using a function expression instead of a function declaration statement.

Comment: Please refer this for full explanation for function scope https://debugmode.net/2020/06/24/a-javascript-function-inside-a-block-scope-simplified/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function declarations are scoped in the same way as `var` declarations (to the function).

If you want to scope something to a block, use `const` or `let`.

You can use a function expression or arrow function to provide a value to a `const` or `let` declaration.

Comment: can it be done without let, const and strict type check?

Comment: @Rahul there are no strict type checks in JavaScript, and no, it cannot be done without `let` or `const`. Why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, if you make it `strict`.

```
'use strict';
{
   function myFunction(){}
}
myFunction(); //error
```

The reason function declarations are hoisted out is because this behavior wasn't defined early enough and implementations extended the behavior in such a way. This was fixed on ES6 but only under `strict` code.

A compatibility layer was offered through Annex B for non-strict code.